# extend HttpClient

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpclient, abstract-class

I'm trying to create a class that extends httpclient but still is abstract.

```
public abstract class Repository : HttpClient
{
    public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //retry logic here
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        while (!IsValid(response))
        {
            Attempts++;
            response = await Retry(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        Attempts = 0;
        return response;
    }
    public int Attempts { get; set; }
    public abstract bool IsValid(HttpResponseMessage response);
    public abstract Task<HttpResponseMessage> Retry(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    public abstract Type GetPageForUri(Uri uri);
    public abstract Task<object> GetItems(Uri uri);
}
```

but when a subclass calls getStringAsync it does not call SendAsync in Repository

```
public class EmailClient : Repository
{
    public override bool IsValid(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> Retry(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
    public override Type GetPageForUri(Uri uri)
    {
        return typeof(EmailPage);
    }
    public override async Task<object> GetItems(Uri uri)
    {
        var emails = await GetStringAsync(uri);
        return emails;
    }
}
```

How what am I doing wrong? should I make a HttpClientHandler and include that with HttpClient? Ive tried to read about virtual if that makes any diffrent. but i dont get it why it does not get called. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why are you subclassing `HttpClient` at all? This looks like a classic case where composition would be much better than inheritance.

Comment: I want other to be able to use all methods that is in `HttpClient` and further extend the class.

Comment: You can use all the methods in `HttpClient` from *within* your class using composition. Why would anyone want to treat `EmailClient` or `Repository` as a plain `HttpClient`? Wouldn't they *only* want to call the newly-introduced methods?

Comment: In the future I want to be able to maybe add a caching layer and an authentication layer. But you are right Im trying to do much in my class.

Comment: Caching and authentication also sound like things which may well be best done with composition, to be honest. But even if you *do* want to add those into the inheritance hierarchy of `Repository`, that still doesn't mean that `Repository` should derive from `HttpClient`.

Comment: Three words: Liskov substitution principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HttpClient is a thin wrapper around an `HttpMessageHandler` implementation (typically `HttpClientHandler`, which properties for features supported across most runtime implementations)

There's actually an `HttpMessageHandler` base class intended for decorators like your retry scenario, `DelegatingHandler`, which you could implement like this:

Something like:

```
public class RetryMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    readonly int retryCount;

    public RetryMessageHandler(int retryCount)
        : this(new HttpClientHandler(), retryCount)
    {
    }

    public RetryMessageHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, int retryCount)
        : base(innerHandler)
    {
        this.retryCount = retryCount;
    }

    public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        for (int i = 0; i<=retryCount; i++)
        {
            response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response;
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Which you would then use like this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(new HttpClientHandler(), 
    new [] { new RetryMessageHandler(3) });

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

Additionally, I'd recommend your `EmailClient` wraps/depends on HttpClient, rather than extending it. (Google "Composition vs Inheritance" for more information on why)